# How do I get the IP of a vsphere_virtual_machine to run ansible-playbook?

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I'm trying to call the IP (ipv4_address) to execute Ansible. When I run plan/apply, I receive the error: "Invalid index: The given key does not identify an element in this collection value."

My configuration:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  network_interface { network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id } 

  name= "terraform-test"
  num_cpus = 2
  memory   = 4096
  guest_id = "centos8_64Guest"
  memory_hot_add_enabled = true
  cpu_hot_add_enabled = true
  cpu_hot_remove_enabled = true

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 20
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

    customize {
      linux_options {
        host_name = "terraform-test"
        domain    = "local"
        time_zone = "Europe/Madrid"
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = "10.20.30.25
        ipv4_netmask = 22
        dns_server_list = ["8.8.8.8"]
      }

      ipv4_gateway = "10.20.30.1"
    }
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 60; ansible-playbook configure.yml -i '${self.clone[4]}',"
  }
}
```

My objective is to run the Playbook on the server you just created with the IP 10.20.30.25.

How do I get the IP of a vsphere_virtual_machine to run ansible-playbook?

Comment: Looks like the error is on `self.clone[4]` are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Looking at the documentation `default_ip_address` should be what you need:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#default_ip_address

Comment: @HelderSepulveda thanks for your comment! I solved it by changing  `'${self.clone[4]}'` to `'${self.default_ip_address}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consolidating @Helder Sapulveda's guidance from comments on the question to an answer for future reference:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "sleep 60; ansible-playbook configure.yml -i '${self.default_ip_address}',"
}
```

You can use the [**default_ip_address** attribute of **vsphere_virtual_machine**](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#default_ip_address) to get the IP address for the ansible-playbook command.